# .NET object design: hardware handles & garbage collection

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm developing a .NET library for easy use of [LibTiePie](http://www.tiepie.com/LibTiePie) by .NET code.

Relevant library code (C#):

```
using Handle = UInt32;

public static class API
{
    [DllImport(@"libtiepie.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void DevClose(Handle device);
};

public class Device
{
    protected Handle _handle;

    public Device(Handle handle)
    {
        _handle = handle;
    }

    ~Device()
    {
        API.DevClose(_handle);
    }
}
```

Program code (C#):

```
Device dev = new Device( some_valid_open_handle );

// Do something useful with dev

dev = null; // How can I make sure that the handle is closed now, as the GC may not cleanup it directly?
```

I can add `Close` method the `Device` class which can be called before releasing the reference. But wonder is there is a better .NET way of implementing this?

Comment: Implement the IDisposable pattern.  Consumers can then do: `using (Device d = new Device(handle)) { ... }` and get deterministic closing of the underlying handle

Comment: @jglouie: make that an answer before someone else does

Comment: I may be wrong but I think you want to be using `IntPtr` rather than `UInt32` for the type of `Handle`.

Comment: You might also want to consider implementing a class derived from SafeHandle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Lukazoid,@Joe This Handle isn't a WinAPI handle but a LibTiePie handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

Consumers can then do:

```
using (Device d = new Device(handle)) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

This will give deterministic closing of the underlying handle.  Also see documentation on the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword.

Instead of calling `API.DevClose(_handle)` in the finalizer, you'd then do it in `Dispose()`.  The MSDN link has a nice example of how this pattern can be used to close native handles.

Comment: If constructing and cleanup isn't within the same scope I should do the cleanup using: `dev.Dispose(); dev = null;`?

Comment: exactly - `using` isn't always appropriate.  In that case, call `Dispose` when it's safe to.  Often this is within a parent container's handling of `Dispose`